# Don't understand PostgreSQL's time zone behaviour

Tags: postgresql, timezone

My local time zone is PRC (china), which is UTC+8, but

```
select (timestamp '2016-09-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'PRC') 
        -  (timestamp '2016-09-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'UTC');
```

returns `-08:00:00`. Shouldn't it be `+08:00:00`?

My PostgreSQL's version is 9.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's doing the right thing - but you have to understand what `at time zone` means when you provide it with an expression *without* a time zone as the left hand side. It's basically interpreting it as a timestamp *in the specified time zone*.

So `'2016-09-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'PRC'` means "the instant in time when it's midnight on September 1st in China" - which is 2016-08-31T16:00:00Z.

And `'2016-09-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'UTC'` means "the instant in time when it's midnight on September 1st in UTC" - which is 2016-09-01T00:00:00Z.

So you're asking for `2016-08-31T16:00:00Z - 2016-09-01T00:00:00Z`, which is indeed -8 hours.